# Finding $\int_C \frac{8z^{11}-3z^6+1}{z^7-1}$

Tags: complex-integration, residue-calculus

Find $\int_C \frac{8z^{11}-3z^6+1}{z^7-1}$ where $C$ is the positively oriented circle $|z| =4$

How should I go about finding this? We know that we have simple poles at the seventh roots of unity, i.e. $z = e^{\frac{n \pi i}{7}}$ and we also note that these poles are interior to $C: |z| =4$.

*Attempt*.

$$\frac{8z^{11}-3z^6+1}{z^7-1} = (8z^{11}-3z^6+1) \cdot \Big( - \frac{1}{1-z^7} \Big)$$

$$ = (8z^{11}-3z^6+1) \cdot \Big( - \displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty (z^7)^n\Big) \hspace{0.5cm} |z| <1$$

$$ = (8z^{11}-3z^6+1) \cdot  \Big( -1 -z^7-z^{14} + \dots\Big) $$

But the two issues I run into here is that the geometric series is only valid for $|z|<1$ whereas we have $|z| =4$ and also I'm not seeing a $\frac{a_{-1}}{z}$ term popping out of this expansion, and I highly doubt the residue is zero. Any advice on what I should do instead?

Comment: Have you tried using Cauchy's integral formula? Or residues Theorem?

Comment: @Luciano My purpose in writing the above geometric series was to attmpt to utilize the residue theorem, but alas to no avail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easier to compute this integral using one resudue at infinity, due all other singularities are in interior of $C$.

$\int\limits_{|z|=4} \frac{8z^{11}-3z^6+1}{z^7-1} dz = -2 \pi i \mathop{\mathrm{Res}}_{z=\infty} \frac{8z^{11}-3z^6+1}{z^7-1} = (1)$

Using $\mathop{\mathrm{Res}}_{z=\infty} f(z) = -\mathop{\mathrm{Res}}_{z=0} \frac{1}{z^2} f\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)$ we obtain $\mathop{\mathrm{Res}}_{z=\infty} \frac{8z^{11}-3z^6+1}{z^7-1} = -\mathop{\mathrm{Res}}_{z=0}\frac{z^{11}-3 z^5+8}{z^6-z^{13}}$.

$\frac{z^{11}-3 z^5+8}{z^6-z^{13}} = z^{-6}(z^{11}-3 z^5+8)(1-z^{7})^{-1} = z^{-6}(z^{11}-3 z^5+8) \left(1 + \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} z^{7 n}\right)$.

So, it is obviously that $\mathop{\mathrm{Res}}_{z=0}\frac{z^{11}-3 z^5+8}{z^6-z^{13}} = -3$. Then we have

$(1) = -2 \pi i \times (-(-3)) = -6 \pi i$.